# AWS S3 policy limitation to regex path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to create an AWS policy to limit the s3:PutObject access on a path in a bucket.
Easy would you say, but:

1. I need to set the path with a regex *MyBucket/*/Folder1/Folder1-1/Object*
2. It's a cross-account access

I try to do this but it's not working.

On **Source Account** User policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket",
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*",
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*",
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": "/*/Folder1/Folder1-1/*"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

On **Destination Account** bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::MyAccountID:user/MyUser"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": "*/Folder1/Folder1-1/*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::MyAccountID:user/MyUser"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*/Folder1/Folder1-1/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

To clarify my Bucket structure :

```
|MyBucket
|-Client1
|-|-Folder1
|-|-|-Folder1-1
|-|-|-|-Object
|-Client1
|-|-Folder1
|-|-|-Folder1-1
|-|-|-|-Object
|-ClientXX
|-|-Folder1
|-|-|-Folder1-1
|-|-|-|-Object
```

I would like my user get PutObject access only not the path `Client*/Folder1/Folder1-1/` could you please help me?

Comment: I do not think this is possible. How are the users uploading the object -- are they using the AWS CLI, or are they doing it via a web page?

Comment: It will be by AWS CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are not supported in the *middle* of a string. However, you could use an [IAM policy variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html):

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:username}/Folder1/Folder1-1/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${aws:username}/Folder1/Folder1-1/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The `${aws:username}` variable will insert the username of the user. This way, the wildcard is at the **end of the string**, which is valid.

This is a common way to allow multiple IAM Users to access the same bucket, but each only receives access to their folder within the bucket. This policy could be **created on an IAM Group**, and the IAM Group could then be assigned to each IAM User without the need to modify it for their particular folder.